# Unterschied zwischen pflegen und betreuen

Tags: meaning, difference, vocabulary

Welchen Unterschied gibt es zwischen den Verben ***pflegen*** und ***betreuen**?*

Ich habe zwei Fehler in meinem Test:

> Die Blumen meiner Mutter wachsen so gut, weil sie sie intensiv *betreut*.
>
> Carola ist zweifache Mutter und *pflegt* wochentags noch drei weitere Kleinkinder.

Im Wörterbuch sehen sie wie Synonyme aus. Aber im Test sollte ich sie umgekehrt stellen.

Comment: Ich finde nicht, dass die umgestellt werden sollten. Eine Blume zu betreuen klingt auch komisch.

Comment: Ich finde beide obigen Sätze korrekt. Für mich bedeutet *pflegen*, dass man handanlegt; *betreuen* heißt für mich, dass man anwesend ist und aufpasst. Wer Senioren pflegt, der wäscht sie auch; wer sie betreut, beaufsichtigt sie und spielt vielleicht Spiele mit ihnen. Deshalb passt zu den Blumen eher pflegen, weil man physisch etwas an ihnen arbeitet, und zu den Kindern passt eher betreuen, weil man aufpasst und sie beschäftigt. "Blumen betreuen" klingt so, als würde man ihnen Musik vorspielen. "Kinder pflegen" klingt so, als wären sie krank und man muss sie füttern und bei ihnen Fieber messen.

Comment: @Chris: ich glaube, dein Text wäre genau die richtige Antwort

Comment: Entschuldigung, ich habe alle verwechselt.. Jetzt ist es richtig - mit den Fehlern. =)

Comment: @arsenbonbon: Für eine richtige Antwort fehlen aber noch Erklärungen zu ein paar Nuancen. Warum heißen "Pflegeeltern" z.B. nicht "Betreuungseltern"? Sie müssen die Kinder ja nicht gesundpflegen, sondern betreuerisch für sie da sein. Warum sagt man nicht, - trotz der eher physischen Arbeit - dass man ein Baby pflegt, wenn man es ganz normal betreut, ohne dass es krank ist? Warum pflegt man alte Menschen, auch wenn sie gar nicht krank, sondern nur alt, sind? Für eine 'richtige' Antwort fehlen einfach zu viele Faktoren, die ich nicht kenne.

Comment: @chris Antworten müssen keinen Anspruch auf Perfektheit erheben... wenn du deinen Kommentar in eine Antwort umwandeltest, hättest du meinen Upvote sicher. Und von den kommentarvotes her nicht nur meinen...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wenn die Wörter **betreut** und **pflegt** auf die Sätze

> Die Blumen meiner Mutter wachsen so gut, weil sie sie intensiv ____.
>
> Carola ist zweifache Mutter und ____ wochentags noch drei weitere Kleinkinder.

verteilt werden sollen, würde ich in die erste Lücke **pflegt** und in die zweite Lücke **betreut** einfügen.

Das Verb **pflegen** beinhaltet meiner Meinung nach eine aktivere, physischere Bedeutung als **betreuen**: Wer jemanden oder etwas pflegt, muss Hand anlegen. Für eine Betreuung reicht gegebenenfalls auch die pure Anwesenheit aus.

Eine weitere Bedeutungsnuance der Pflege ist, dass sich ohne sie ein Zustand eventuell verschlechtern würde: Werden Kranke nicht gepflegt, können sie sterben; werden Blumen nicht gepflegt, gehen sie ein. Die Betreuung ist eher eine zusätzliche Zuwendung, deren Fehlen aber keine Verschlimmerung des Zustandes zur Folge hätte: Wenn Kinder nicht betreut werden, laufen sie halt unbeaufsichtigt herum; wenn Senioren nicht betreut werden, fühlen sie sich halt einsam; aber "fatal" wäre dies nicht. (Das ist nicht meine Meinung, ich versuche die Nuance nur in Worte zu fassen.)

- Zu den Blumen passt eher **pflegen**, denn man arbeitet physisch etwas an ihnen (man gießt sie, rupft verwelkte Blätter ab). Betreut man Blumen, dann klingt das so, als würde man für sie singen, ihnen Musik vorspielen oder ihnen einfach nur Gesellschaft leisten. Man könnte eine Situation konstruieren, in der in einem Gartenmarkt ein Mitarbeiter vorgestellt wird mit den Worten: "Das ist Stefan; er betreut die Blumen." Das würde dann aber bedeuten, dass Stefan für die Blumenabteilung verantwortlich ist und eher die sich für die Blumen interessierenden Kunden betreut als die Blumen per se.
- Zu den Kindern passt eher **betreuen**, weil man auf sie aufpassen muss und ihnen eine Beschäftigung gibt. Man kann Kinder auch pflegen; das setzt dann aber voraus, dass sie krank sind und man aktiv darauf hinarbeitet, dass sie wieder gesund werden. (Beachte aber den Begriff "Pflegeeltern" (foster parents): Sie pflegen Kinder nicht in dem Sinne, dass diese krank wären; sie haben eher eine betreuende Rolle.)
- Bei Senioren würden beide Begriffe (**pflegen** und **betreuen**) passen, haben dann aber eine unterschiedliche Bedeutung: Wer Senioren pflegt, der wäscht sie beispielsweise; wer sie betreut, der beaufsichtigt und beschäftigt sie eher.

Comment: Man beachte auch die Etymologie von "betreuen": Laut  [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/betreuen) stammt das Wort vom Mittelhochdeutschen "betriuwen" und bedeutet "schützen". Einen kranken Angehörigen oder Nachbars Blumen muß man natürlich auch beschützen, aber hier steht dann doch eher die Pflege im Vordergrund.